# Trying to create a file through Bitbucket API, "when performing an edit, the author must have an e-mail address"

Tags: git, api, bitbucket

I'm trying to use the Bitbucket server API to create a file in my remote repository. I've been using the query outlined in [this documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/rest/v809/api-group-repository/#api-api-latest-projects-projectkey-repos-repositoryslug-browse-path-put) and I have been able to successfully do this using an HTTP access token associated with my personal Bitbucket account. However, I am ultimately trying to authenticate using an HTTP access token created in my *repository*, and, while I have created such a token in my repository's settings, using that token returns a 400 response with the message "When performing an edit, the author must have an e-mail address". I have given that token full admin privileges, but I see no way to associate an email address to a repository's HTTP access token and the only support case I've found that contains a concrete answer says to just use a different account with an email address, which I cannot do for this project.

Does anyone know how to get around this? Is there a way I can associate an email address with a repository's HTTP access token or include an email address in the post headers somehow?

Edit: Just in case it turns out to be relevant, here's the code I'm using to send the API query:

```
import json
import requests

def handler(context, inputs):
    jsonOut = json.dumps(inputs, separators=(',', ':'))
    print("Inputs were {0}".format(jsonOut))

    # Set the API endpoint URL
    project = '{project name}'
    repo = '{repo name}'
    fileName = 'test789.txt'
    url = f'https://{{My Bitbucket server url}}/rest/api/latest/projects/{project}/repos/{repo}/browse/{fileName}' 
    print('url: ' + url)

    token = "{my HTTP access token}"

    # Set the headers with the encoded key
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }

    # Set the body for the API call
    branchName = 'branch-name'
    content = inputs['contents']
    commitMsg = 'Test creating a file with a python script'
    files = {
        'branch': branchName,
        'content': content,
        'message': commitMsg,
        'sourceBranch': 'master'
    }

    # Make the API call to create the new branch
    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("Status code: " + str(response.status_code) + "\n" + response.json()["errors"][0]["message"])

    print("YML file pushed to BitBucket successfully.")

inputs = {"contents": "Flippity Floo"}
handler("context", inputs)
```